# Limit a view in Django

Tags: django, view, limit, extend

I have a problem in my Django project. I extend the Django user with a new 1-to-1 relationship in a named WebUser model. I have normal users and users with this new relationship. How can I limit the same views to only show them to the users, so they have the relation with Webusers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing a specific Django solution I can help you with a Python solution. If you use decorators you can limit the access to the webuser view:

```
# Decorator for limit access when user dont have relation with WebUser
def webuser_required(f):
    def trace(*args, **kw):
        try:
            login = isinstance(request.user.webuser, WebUser)
            return f(*args, **kw)
        except:
            return ....
    return trace
```

You can use it:

```
@webuser_required
def yourview(....):
    yourcode
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this solution. It allow me control every view without add any code inside the view function. So usefull!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def limited_view(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated(): 
      if request.user.web_profile is not None:
          # show 
      else: 
          # dont show
```

do you mean something like this?

Comment: Thanks, I had thinking a solution like this but I don't want duplicate the code in every view to take the two ways (normal user / user.webuser)